# Reshape a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have the following data frame

```
structure(list(X1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
    V1 = c(1, NA, 1, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V2 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA), V3 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0.125, 0.75, 1)), .Names = c("X1", 
"V1", "V2", "V3"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want the df to be like this:

```
structure(list(X1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V1 = c(1L, NA, 1L, 0L), 
    V2 = c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 1), V3 = c(0, 0.125, 0.75, 1)), .Names = c("X1", 
"V1", "V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4"))
```

My idea was selecting the columns, deled the NA’s and bind the columns. But there are na’s in the set and something tells me that the idea will not work / is the long way.

Q) what is the best way to reshape the df?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you lose the `x1` values exept `1`, why is the `NA` in `x2` preserved? You would get your result by `cbind(df[1:4, 1:2], sapply(df_[, 3:4], function(x) x[!is.na(x)]))` for example, as you described it... However, to me, your description is not unambiguous.

Comment: @lukeA Sorry, didn't see your answer. You should post it.

Comment: Actually I don't know what the OP wants, so just leave it there.. :)

Comment: @lukeA Now, I understand the difference between your solution and mine.  Yours is selecting the first two columns, but I am selecting the NA values if it occurs between two non-NA elements and remove it otherwise

Comment: @Adam As lukeA mentioned, the `X1=1` in the expected result is not clear.  What is the criteria for selecting only that value?

Comment: @akrun and lukeA, Thank you both for the commands. Why do you lose the x1>>> it is no problem if X1 is deleted. It is a sloppy fast-don’t-think-copy it thing. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Adam Thanks for the clarification.  If you need to select the NA elements based on their occurence within the first and last non-NA element, the solution I posted should work, given that the lengths of the different columns after the removal of NA elements are the same (which is same in the example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
res <- data.frame(X1=1, sapply(df1[-1], function(x) {
              indx <- which(!is.na(x))
               x[min(indx):max(indx)]}))
res
#  X1 V1   V2    V3
#1  1  1 0.00 0.000
#2  1 NA 0.25 0.125
#3  1  1 0.50 0.750
#4  1  0 1.00 1.000
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can just consider `pmax` and `split`, something like this:

```
as.data.frame(split(do.call(pmax, c(mydf[-1], na.rm = TRUE)), mydf$X1))
#   X1   X2    X3
# 1  1 0.00 0.000
# 2 NA 0.25 0.125
# 3  1 0.50 0.750
# 4  0 1.00 1.000
```

If you really need a column of ones, you can easily add that in with `cbind`.